# Pass all keywords only arguments to other function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with situations where I have a lot of [Keyword-Only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) and I need to pass them to another function which gets them all as keyword-only arguments too.

Supouse I have the next code:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
        pass


def create_instance(*, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
    # I want to prevent to do the following sentence
    A(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3, arg4=arg4, arg5=arg5, arg6=arg6)
```

There is any trick to pass all keyword-only arguments from a function to another?. I mean something like

```py
def create_instance(*, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
    A(*)  # dummy code that pretends to pass all keyword-only args
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: well you could def create_instance(*args) and then pass args to A

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese `create_instance(**kwargs)` since they are keyword only, no?

Comment: @IainShelvington yep

Comment: I need to maintain the keyword-only arguments in the function.

Comment: @LucasVazquez you **really** should just do `A(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3, arg4=arg4, arg5=arg5, arg6=arg6)` there is no good reason to avoid that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I look there isn't any that I can do then. Below is a good answer from @ donkopotamus, but, how the comments in them say, its very smart, but hacky and unpythonic bc is implicit and can create some bugs. Only the people who absolutely control the local variables and they aren't vague can use it, but its keep hard to maintain

Answer (score 2):

In the very simple case above where the arguments match precisely:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
        pass
```

then you could use the rather hacky

```
def create_instance(*, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
    return A(**locals())
```

In the more general case, where `create_instance` takes other arguments:

```
def create_instance(x, y, *, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, blah):
    return A(
        **{k: v for k, v in locals()
           if k in "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6".split()})
```

If you wish to wrap this up into something reusable, and more explicit to the reader (but still somewhat buyer beware) then you could do something like the following:

```
# general purpose function for binding kw-only arguments from a namespace
def implicit_binder(f, *, namespace):
    return functools.partial(
        f,
        **{p.name: namespace[p.name]
           for p in inspect.signature(f).parameters.values()
           if p.kind == inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY})

def create_instance(*, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6):
    return implicit_binder(A, namespace=locals())(<you could pass other args here>)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because `A(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)` doesn't even work

Comment: Whatever, `A(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3, arg4=arg4, arg5=arg5, arg6=arg6)` I mean, this just introduces insane hacks for no discernible benefit.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because the simple example ... which is what the question **actually asked**, is **clearly better** in terms of typing ... and the latter is can be the basis of a decorator.

Comment: No, it is *clearly worse*, since it is implicit. Anyone reading that for the first time is going to do a double-take. Code is written once, and read many times. This is just the sort of thing that should get eviscerated in any good code review. And look, I'm not attacking you, you just answered the question, but for anyone reading, this should clearly be avoided.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I clearly indicated it was **hacky** in my answer ... that it disagrees with your emphatic comment that "No there isn't" any way it can be done seems to have annoyed you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How do you feel about the addition?

Comment: It is a very good answer, hacky and smart, but not recommended because it's very implicit.
I upvote it, but I don't select as the correct answer because there isn't an official method that I should use, I prefer to keep the question open, and if in any moment an official implementation or a more pythonic answer appears, look for the correct answer again.
Another motive to not select as the correct answer is that I want to prevent some users to use these methods because can create hard maintaining code and only works for experienced users that know what are doing.

Comment: The comment I just left you was for your answer before the update. Then I will look at your updated code and leave you a new comment, thanks for these tricks, they are helping me to learn more about python anyway, and to avoid in the future constructions that lead me to have the code structured in the way in which i have it now